# Gupshup-Wit.ai integration very slow / getting stuck

Tags: gupshup

I am using Gupshup IDE Bot Builder and Wit.ai for a ChatBot widget on my website.
I have made the same bot in FB-messenger without Gupshup (node-js) and it works fine.

When using Gupshup, the bot often gets stuck and does not respond. 
This also happens when I test it in the Gupshup proxy bot. So it seems like the problem is with the communication between Gupshup and Wit.ai.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Will it improve if I build my bot outside and link it too Gupshup?

Answer (score 0):

The APIs and behavior of wit.ai have changed recently. Gupshup will update the wit.ai template soon.

In the mean time, you can integrate the wit.ai API directly into the bot on Gupshup.
These resources should help:

1. Wit.ai [quick start guide](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart)
2. Gupshup's [making HTTP calls guide](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/making-http-calls)

This will be a GET call.

Comment: and what about the runActions() method in NLP code template which has been deprecated ? <code> witClient.runActions(sessionId, event.message, witContext, (e, context1) => {
        if (e) {
            console.log('Oops! Got an error: ' + e);
            return;
        }
        context.console.log('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        //context.sendResponse('No keyword found : '+event.message); 
    });</code>

Comment: The wit.ai template on Gupshup will be deprecated and removed hence you can use the suggested approach to integrate with wit.ai

Comment: @Shreyans I need some help with gupshup API, I am new to programming and I want to program a whatsapp bot in python using gupshup API, Can you help me get a head start, I have looked at documentation but I could not understand much of it
I would really appreciate if you can help me out