# Gupshup NLP Code template with Wit.ai

Tags: javascript, wit.ai, gupshup

I'm wondering why this template has still a method which has been deprecated recently and will be no longer used in February:

```
    var witContext = {};
    witClient.runActions(sessionId, event.message, witContext, (e, context1) => {
        if (e) {
            console.log('Oops! Got an error: ' + e);
            return;
        }
        context.console.log('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        //context.sendResponse('No keyword found : '+event.message); 
    });
```

How can we use in this template/message() method which is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

As wit.ai is shutting down the bot engine there is no point of having the template. We at Gupshup will be removing the template and will allow migration of any old bot with wit.ai template to our new IDE bot builder where you can easily do the migration as explained [here](https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-stories-migration-tutorial)

As of now, you can use the suggested approach in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327145/gupshup-wit-ai-integration-very-slow-getting-stuck/45484745?noredirect=1#comment80217293_45484745).